# What is difference between middleware in routes and middleware in controller's constructor?

Tags: php, laravel

I am quite new to the laravel and want to understand about middlewares in deep. I want to know that what is the major difference between attaching middleware with the route or adding the middleware in the controller's constructor.
For example it is a constructor of the controller named `UserController`

```
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('age');
}
```

Let's assume that it is the route of the same controller i.e `UserController`

```
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('age');
```

My main question is that should I need to add middleware in both routes and controller's constructor or just in one of them?

Comment: I personally put them in the controller - that way I know which middlewares apply to which of the methods in the controller in the same file. And if there for some reason are multiple routes to the same endpoint, you always run those middlewares first. You generally don't need them in both places, imo.

Comment: @Qirel So I don't need to add middleware in the route then if that route belongs to the controller in which I have already added the middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both will perform same task,it`s just you can write in two different ways.

`However, it is more convenient to specify middleware within your controller's constructor. Using the middleware method from your controller's constructor, you may easily assign middleware to the controller's action. You may even restrict the middleware to only certain methods on the controller class.`

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/middleware-in-controller-or-on-route

Comment: should I need to add middleware in both routes and controller's constructor or just in one of them?

Comment: @ZainFarooq just in one of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answering.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your situation if you have condition in the controller you must use first case or not it's better to use second case.

Answer (score 0):

````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
public function __construct() {
  $this->middleware('age');
}
```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Global middlewares are those that will be running during every HTTP request of your application. In the $middleware property of your app/Http/Kernel.php class, you can list all the global middleware for your project.

```````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
Route::get('user/profile', function () {
    //
})->middleware('age');
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````
When you want middlewares to specific routes, you have to add the middleware with a key for your app/Http/Kernel.php file and such middlewares are called route middleware. $routeMiddleware by default holds entries for the middleware that are already incorporated in Laravel. For adding your custom middleware, you need to append them to the list and add a key of your choice

[link]https://www.w3schools.in/laravel-tutorial/middleware/
````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````````